# News Feed on Android

Tags: android, facebook, feed

I'd like to create something of the style the facebook newsfeed.

I understand that this should not be simple. So I would just like some idea of ​​how I can develop it.

That's what I want to create:

https://lh4.ggpht.com/HG8XNTrr_sS5FXhd_zFKAoAB9KDPzmD9LEopuDj3kxJdEO8gUvv2IyFNJUd50XMhO-w

I believe that Facebook should make a request and have an xml/json. After receiving the response, the app should style the content according to information received from the API.

Do you have a tutorial / idea how I could do something similar?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty good tutorial for ListViews. Essentially, every "post" in the Newsfeed will be an item in the ListView. You have to bind your data to the ListView and provide the views for each post.

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: Thank you. That link you sent is very good indeed. In this case, the ListView generates the list. As I put the data in the shape of "table"?